# Generating Function Sum and Combinotorics

Tags: combinatorics

Problem:
The sum $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\binom n2}{4^n} ~~=~~ \frac{\binom 22}{16}+\frac{\binom 32}{64}+\frac{\binom 42}{256}+\cdots$ has a finite value. Determine that value.

---

I am quite stuck on how to do this. Can somebody give me <**only**> a hint or hints to get going? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: start repeatedly differentiating the generating function for $\frac{1}{1 - x}$.

Answer:

> We have the generating function/Maclaurin series for $\frac{1}{1 - x}$:
>   $$\frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots \quad |x| < 1$$
>   Differentiating, which we do term by term does not change the radius of convergence, giving us
>   $$\frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \ldots \quad |x| < 1.$$
>   Differentiating a second time gives us
>   $$\frac{2}{(1 - x)^3} = (2 \cdot 1) + (3 \cdot 2)x + (4 \cdot 3)x^2 + \ldots \quad |x| < 1$$
>   Recall that $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{1}{2}n(n - 1)$, so we have
>   $$\frac{1}{(1 - x)^3} = \binom{2}{2} + \binom{3}{2}x + \binom{4}{2}x^2 + \ldots \quad |x| < 1.$$
>   Dividing by $16$, and substituting $x = \frac{1}{4}$, we get
>   $$\frac{4}{27} = \frac{1}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{4}\right)^3} = \frac{\binom{2}{2}}{4^2} + \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{4^3} + \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{4^4} + \ldots$$

Comment: Hold on...let me try again.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to expand on this.

Comment: I don't know why the previous answer was deleted. Yes, may you please expand that?

Comment: @Max0815 hey, I deleted my answer because I misinterpreted the question. Your task was to give an explicit value, not to see convergence (that explains why the problem is not so immediate), and I got that backwards. I don't think I can give more insight than the one given in this answer already :)

Comment: @Guido A. your convergence was quite useful into moving deeper into the problem, but as I went to dinner, it was deleted and I couldn't continue. However, maybe this can help me too. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: @Theo Bendit thanks for your hints, I will play around for a while, and see if I get to any avail. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I preferred to minimize confusion by not leaving it there. @TheoBendit's answer is great though, you should be able to finish the problem from here.

Comment: @Max0815 I changed the hint, now that I actually thought about the path to the full solution.

Comment: @Guido A. its ok, I think I still can solve the problem... I think.
(ahh I cant do another @) So Theo Bendit weren't all four hints along the way to solve the problem??? Why did you take those away?

Comment: Sorry @Max0815, I thought from your answer, you had given up. I took away the hints, because I realised as I was doing it that I thought the problem required more work than it did.

Comment: @Theo Bendit Its ok. :) They say if you don't give up, you learn, and that's exactly what happened today :) I actually solved it :) through the 4 hints (I clicked on edit and looked at them :P). Thanks to everyone who helped! Your answers and appreciated!!!!!!

Comment: @anyone, especially to Theo Bendit. My solution is below. Is this a good approach and solution? Can there be any improvements???

Comment: Where is your solution?

Comment: @TB it was long.. We know a generating function whose coefficients are of the form $\binom n2$: namely,
$$\frac 1{(1-x)^3} = \binom 22 + \binom 32x + \binom 42x^2 + \cdots.$$
Substituting $x=\frac 14$ in this expansion, we get
$$\frac 1{\left(1-\frac 14\right)^3} = \binom 22 + \frac{\binom 32}4 + \frac{\binom 42}{16} + \cdots.$$
Dividing by $16$ gives
$$\frac 1{16}\cdot \frac 1{\left(1-\frac 14\right)^3} = \frac{\binom 22}{16} + \frac{\binom 32}{64} + \frac{\binom 42}{256} + \cdots.$$
The right side is the sum we wished to determine, and the left side simplifies to $\boxed{\frac 4{27}}$.

Comment: Yep! That's pretty much exactly what I did too. I don't know if it could be improved, but it seems short and to-the-point. I personally like combinatorial proofs, but I couldn't think of any :-/

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Ok, so it doesn't need to be fixed or anything? :) ...I don't get what you mean by that you cant think of any..i thought you just wrote a proof in this post?

Comment: And again, I want to thank you all very much! :)

Comment: I mean, I can't think of a *combinatorial* proof, where this series represent counting or measuring something. It's not common to see them with infinite series, but I always want to try combinatorial proofs when I see binomial coefficients!

Comment: Oh....i dont think it is really meant to be a combinatorial proof.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$S=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \binom{n}{2}x^n =\frac 12 \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n+1) x^n=\frac 12 \sum_{n=2}^\infty[n(n-1)+2n] x^n$$
$$S=\frac 12 \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1) x^n+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty n x^n=\frac {x^2}2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1) x^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=2}^\infty n x^{n-1}$$
$$S=\frac {x^2}2 \left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty  x^n \right)''+x\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty  x^n \right)'$$ When finished, let $x=\frac 14$.

Comment: Got it! YAYAYAYAYAY!!! I ACTUALLY SOLVED IT WITHOUT LOOKING AT THE SOLUTION :):):):):). Thanks for all you guy's help! Sadly, I would love to upvote you all, but I dont have enough reputation :(.